# How do I serve out a WMS using mapnik?

Tags: wms, mapnik

I have an old Mapnik's XML file, from which I need to serve out data as a WMS service.

I've gone through the Mapnik site, and I didn't find anything. I've also looked at Mapnik's [OGC server](https://github.com/mapnik/OGCServer), and looks like there has been no development in the last 10 months.

How do I serve out a WMS using mapnik?

Comment: I fear that the OGC server is your only native alternative even there used to be also this https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Paleoserver. But I recommend rather to install http://mapproxy.org/ which can turn Mapnik into WMS for you.